# Specifying EPSG transformation method in GeoTools?

Tags: geotools

I am a software developer who knows a bit about Gis/Geodesy, but I am not an expert so I might misuse terminology somewhat.

I have been tasked to extend an app in Java and have a need to transform data from one Coord System to another. We started using GeoTools which lets us transform using EPSG codes.

```
    private MathTransform getMathTransformForEpsgCode(String epsgCode) throws FactoryException {
    MathTransform sourceToTargetConversion = null;
    try {
        // Get the result SourceCRS
        CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS_FACTORY.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(epsgCode);
        // Create and apply Transform
        sourceToTargetConversion = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, TARGET_CRS);
    } catch (NoSuchAuthorityCodeException e) {
        log.info("No CRS found for code, assuming it is a transform", e);
        throw e;
    }

    return sourceToTargetConversion;
}
```

Which was then used something like the following

```
JTS.transform(coordinate, coordinate, returnedMathtransform);
```

HOWEVER, what we want to do is actually specify the math transformation method used (Note: I think this is akin I think to this question "[How to specify transformation method when using ogr2ogr to reproject geometry?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290148/how-to-specify-transformation-method-when-using-ogr2ogr-to-reproject-geometry)".

Is this possible with GeoTools?

- Ideally specifying the math transform using an ESPG code (i.e. http://epsg.io/27700-5339)
- Alternativly specifying 3 or 7 parameters

So I am a wee bit out of my depth here (but learning fast). I believe the above can be accomplished using a (licensed) ESRI java api. Can it be achieved easily in GeoTools or any other open source libraries, again ideally usable as a java api and not the command line.

Comment: Note that http://epsg.io is not the original EPSG dataset. The original one is at http://www.epsg-registry.org.

Answer (score 5):

First you need to download the NTv2 file you need (e.g. from your [national mapping agency](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/navigation-technology/os-net/ostn02-ntv2-format.html)), you then need to save the `.gsb` file in `src/main/resources/org/geotools/referencing/factory/gridshift` and proceed as normal. If you need a custom transform there are some [examples](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/crshandling/coordtransforms.html#add-grid-shift-transform-files) in the GeoServer documentation.

For example this program:

```
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException;
import org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.MathTransform;

public class OSTN02 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAuthorityCodeException, FactoryException  {
    MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(CRS.decode("epsg:4326"), CRS.decode("epsg:27700"));
    System.out.println(transform);
  }

}
```

Initially outputs:

```
CONCAT_MT[PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]], 
  PARAM_MT["Ellipsoid_To_Geocentric", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314245179]], 
  PARAM_MT["Position Vector transformation (geog2D domain)", 
    PARAMETER["dx", -446.45598741153583], 
    PARAMETER["dy", 125.1609926805404], 
    PARAMETER["dz", -542.071732141031], 
    PARAMETER["ex", -0.1499999999990687], 
    PARAMETER["ey", -0.24699999999846645], 
    PARAMETER["ez", -0.841999999994772], 
    PARAMETER["ppm", 20.48940738963445]], 
  PARAM_MT["Geocentric_To_Ellipsoid", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6377563.396], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356256.909237285]], 
  PARAM_MT["Transverse_Mercator", 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6377563.396], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356256.909237285], 
    PARAMETER["central_meridian", -2.0], 
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 48.99999999999999], 
    PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996012717], 
    PARAMETER["false_easting", 400000.0], 
    PARAMETER["false_northing", -100000.0]]]
```

but with the grid file provided gives:

```
CONCAT_MT[PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]], 
  INVERSE_MT[PARAM_MT["NTv2", 
      PARAMETER["Latitude and longitude difference file", "OSTN02_NTv2.gsb"]]], 
  PARAM_MT["Transverse_Mercator", 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6377563.396], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356256.909237285], 
    PARAMETER["central_meridian", -2.0], 
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 48.99999999999999], 
    PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996012717], 
    PARAMETER["false_easting", 400000.0], 
    PARAMETER["false_northing", -100000.0]]]
```

Comment: Hi Ian, 

Thanks for the speedy reply. 

So am I right in saying that these gridshift files are a more accurate transformation between two different coordinate systems from the default? 

What we need is to provide the client with the choice of which transformation to use, they have operations globally and 'my clients clients' all specify different transformations.

Comment: The closest I have got is to create a transform via WKT. So something like this:
DefaultMathTransformFactory defaultTrans = new DefaultMathTransformFactory()
String myCustomTransformWkt = “CONCAT_MT etc…..”;
MathTransForm myCustomTransform = defaultTrans.createFromWkt(myCustomTransformWkt );

Comment: For any specific EPSG code (e.g. EPSG:27700) you can specify a grid file and that will become the new default transform for that projection. So provided you don't have some clients in the UK who want low accuracy and some who want high you should be ok.

Comment: Ian, OP says that there will be worldwide customers. It's possible that some will not have NTv2 file for their areas of interest.

Comment: There are a lot of NTv2 files (see the [GeoServer docs for the list](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/crshandling/coordtransforms.html#ntv2)). GeoTools also supports [NADCOM](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/crshandling/coordtransforms.html#nadcon)  Or allows you to [specify a custom transform](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/crshandling/coordtransforms.html#examples) though I've never needed to try either of the 2nd two.

Comment: Thanks again guys for your feedback.
Apologies I should have mentioned this, but didn't realise it was important.
My client works on assets on the seabed in various locations around the world, do these grid shifts only work on land?
I downloaded the grid shift file from the ordinance survey, then tried to open in notepad++ and it obviously is a non text format. Is there a way to open this file to examine the contents in human readable form. Additionally is it possible to specify your own grid shift file for all the coord system you know are relevant to the current job?

Comment: So for instance one job might be offshore Brazil, we drop in the relevant gsb file for that project and the application works away. Next job is offshore Namibia, again we drop in the relevant gsb file and away we go.
This is a new area to me (as you may have guessed...), So I am just trying to figure out what is possible via grid shift files to perform a custom transformation on off shore vector data worldwide.

Comment: I think the land/sea interface depends on the grid creator - the UK one goes 10km off shore. You can add as many grid files as you need they will all have different names

Comment: there is a txt file aswell as the gsb file in the download

Comment: It is worth highlighting the NTv2 version of OSTN02 is an approximation to the authoritative OSTN02 transform.  Errors of up to 90mm. Use of the NTv2 OSTN02 should not be promoted as 'high accuracy'.

Comment: 90mm is high accuracy in my book, I seriously doubt many people are mapping to anything like that accuracy

Comment: Ostn02/15 is also used for precision survey engineering data - where 90mm is a very significant blunder.